# A family of closed sets in $\mathbb{R^{p}}$ where no set in this family contains a non-void open set

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to understand above claim, but it doesn't make sense to me. The only example I can think is singletons, but is there any one who can give a good example(s) or at least explain this thing so that I can visualize? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many-many-many singletons, and one [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). Or in $\Bbb R^n$ it's even easier to visualize using $n-1$-dimensional closed surfaces!

Comment: You can find also with positive measure take $B_n (0,1)/\mathbb{Q}^n$ and then use fact you can approximate any measurable set with a closed set from below(approximate in terms of measure).

Comment: There isn't a claim in your title.